# Windows Batch Script Generates runtime error R6016 - not enough space for thread data

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I am running a Batch Script that is 1 `FOR /F %%i` loop and it is currently running over 5k files totaling 62mb. I am using Windows 7. The error doesn't generate everytime I run it. It seems to only generate after I run the script multiple times (for testing). Once I hit the 10 OKs for the error the script continues and may or may not throw the error again. The last time I had it open I was running a separate cmd line window with PROMPT $T active, and various other programs open in the background. Eventually I will need to run this over a folder containing 40gb of data and I would like to avoid the clicking catastrophe of Runtime Error R6016.

Any suggestions on what I can do to avoid this error? Need more info? let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly are you running Bash on a windows machine?

Comment: What are you doing in the DO portion of the loop? I suspect that is where the error is being generated. I don't think it is the batch script itself, but rather some program you are executing within the loop.

Comment: I am running nConvert on .jpg images. Would `OPTION BATCH CONTINUE` suppress the error messages?